# How do i make the anchorCheck and anchorX icons/buttons update a specific field on Firestore Database?

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code

```
<script>
            var tbody = document.getElementById('tableD');

            function AddItemToTable(submit, name, cid, pnum, dname, stm, status, action) {
                let trow = document.createElement("tr");
                let td1 = document.createElement("td");
                let td2 = document.createElement("td");
                let td3 = document.createElement("td");
                let td4 = document.createElement("td");
                let td5 = document.createElement("td");
                let td6 = document.createElement("td");
                let td7 = document.createElement("td");
                let td8 = document.createElement("td");



                td1.innerHTML = submit;
                td2.innerHTML = name;
                td3.innerHTML = cid;
                td4.innerHTML = pnum;
                td5.innerHTML = dname;

                // Create a hyperlink element for td7
                let hyperlink = document.createElement("a");
                hyperlink.href = stm;
                hyperlink.innerText = "Link";

                td6.appendChild(hyperlink);

                td7.innerHTML = status;

                if (status === "Pending") {
                    td7.className = "pending";
                } else if (status === "Accepted") {
                    td7.className = "accepted";
                } else if (status === "Rejected") {
                    td7.className = "rejected";
                }

                // Create the anchor elements and set their classes
                let anchorDownload = document.createElement("a");
                anchorDownload.className = "bi bi-download";

                let anchorCheck = document.createElement("a");
                anchorCheck.className = "bi bi-check-lg";

                let anchorX = document.createElement("a");
                anchorX.className = "bi bi-x-lg";

                anchorDownload.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    // Call the function to open the download modal
                    openDownloadModal();
                });



                **// Add event listener for check icon
                anchorCheck.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    // Change the status to "Accepted" in the corresponding row
                    td7.innerHTML = "Accepted";
                    td7.className = "accepted";

                });

                // Add event listener for X icon
                anchorX.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    // Change the status to "Rejected" in the corresponding row
                    td7.innerHTML = "Rejected";
                    td7.className = "rejected";

                });**



                // Append the anchor elements to td9
                td8.appendChild(anchorDownload);
                td8.appendChild(anchorCheck);
                td8.appendChild(anchorX);

                // Append all the td elements to the table row
                trow.appendChild(td1);
                trow.appendChild(td2);
                trow.appendChild(td3);
                trow.appendChild(td4);
                trow.appendChild(td5);
                trow.appendChild(td6);
                trow.appendChild(td7);
                trow.appendChild(td8);


                tbody.appendChild(trow);
            }

            function AddAllItemsToTable(Theapplication) {
                tbody.innerHTML = "";
                Theapplication.forEach(element => {
                    AddItemToTable(element.submit, element.name, element.cid, element.pnum, element.dname, element.stm, element.status);
                })
            }
        </script>





        <script type="module">
            
            import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.1.0/firebase-app.js";

            
            const firebaseConfig = {
                apiKey: "*****************",
                authDomain: "*****************",
                databaseURL: "*****************",
                projectId: "*****************",
                storageBucket: "*****************",
                messagingSenderId: "*****************7",
                appId: "*****************",
                measurementId: "*****************"
            };

            // Initialize Firebase
            const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

            import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc, getDocs, onSnapshot, collection, updateDoc } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.1.0/firebase-firestore.js"

            const db = getFirestore();



            async function GetAllDataRealtime() {
                const dbRef = collection(db, "application");

                onSnapshot(dbRef, (querySnapshot) => {
                    var applications = [];

                    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        applications.push(doc.data())
                    });
                    AddAllItemsToTable(applications);
                })





            }



            window.onload = GetAllDataRealtime;


        </script>
```

And i would like the anchorCheck and anchorX to update a field named "status" and change it to Accepted and Rejected on respoective icon clicks.

I tried making a function on the first  that updates the field but it doesn't work. I tried putting the function on the second one, but the innerHTML changes doesn't work. I need the both functions to wrok at the same click/time